# Porting Kernel From Another Device

Tags: android, kernel, porting, smartphone, cyanogenmod

I am developing CM10 for my device, and I want to port 3.4 kernel from another device (because my device doesn't have 3.4 kernel).

I am fairly new to android development, therefore I need some guidance.

Yes, I have the CM10 source and I have set up my device and vendor directories. I still need to download the kernel source.

Another question is that my phone is Huawei Ideos X5. What would be the best phone to port the kernel from. Should it be a device that has the same specs as mine?

If you have any questions then please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: check this post for similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414289/guidance-regarding-android-kernel-porting-from-one-device-to-other?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to pull off the kernel porting, if both devices are the same architecture (i.e. ARMv7), and the kernel has no drivers statically linked to it. For the first part, you can check /proc/cpuinfo on your device - generally any processor with the same feature set should work.

The concern, however, will be modules - the device drivers needed to run the underlying hardware (GPS, accelerometer, framebuffer, etc). You are likely not going to have the source for those, so if you are porting a kernel you must make sure the kernel version magic is identical - up to the minor and extra versions.